# bluetooth connection cannot be established between android and pc

Tags: java, android, import, bluetooth

i am trying to send my phone's gyro,accelerometers values to my pc using bluetooth,
i am using bluecove java api for client side (pc).

server code:

```
package com.example.kphan.bluetooth_transfer;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.bluetooth.*;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener  {
    private SensorManager senSensorManager;
    private Sensor senAccelerometer ;
    private Sensor senGyroscope;
    private TextView tv1;
    private TextView tv2;
    private boolean clicked = false;
    private float AccX,AccY,AccZ,GyroX,GyroY,GyroZ;
    private Button mvBtn;
    private BluetoothAdapter bAdapter;
    String deviceName,deviceAddress;
    private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
    private Handler mHandler;
    String TAG = "bluetooth";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) throws NullPointerException{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
        mvBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_send);
        bAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if(!bAdapter.isEnabled()){
            Intent enableBTIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBTIntent,1);
        }
        senSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        senAccelerometer = senSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        senGyroscope = senSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
        senSensorManager.registerListener(this, senAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        senSensorManager.registerListener(this, senGyroscope, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if(pairedDevices.size() > 0){
            for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices){
                deviceName = device.getName();
                deviceAddress = device.getAddress();
                mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
                mConnectThread.start();
            }
        }




    }
    private class ConnectThread extends Thread{
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
        private final UUID myUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
        public ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;

        ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device){
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            mmDevice = device;
            try{
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myUUID);
            }catch(IOException e){}
            mmSocket = tmp;
            mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);

        }
        public void run(){
            bAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            try{
                mmSocket.connect();
                mConnectedThread.start();

            }catch(IOException e){
                try{
                    mmSocket.close();
                }catch(IOException e1){
                    return;
                }
            }

        }
        public void close(){
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public boolean socketAccquired(){
            if(mmSocket != null) {
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread{
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        private byte[] mmBuffer;
        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket){
            mmSocket = socket;
            OutputStream tmpOut= null;
            try{
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            }catch(IOException e){}
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;


        }
        public void run(){
            mmBuffer = new byte[1024];
        }
        public void write(byte[] bytes){
            String message = new String(bytes);
            Log.d(TAG,"...Data to send: " + message + "...");
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);

            }catch(IOException e){}

        }
        public void cancel(){
            try{
                mmSocket.close();
            }catch(IOException e){}
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {

        Sensor mySensor = sensorEvent.sensor;
        if(mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
            AccX = sensorEvent.values[0];
            AccY = sensorEvent.values[1];
            AccZ = sensorEvent.values[2];
            String x = String.valueOf(AccX);
            String y = String.valueOf(AccY);
            String z = String.valueOf(AccZ);
            String x1 = String.valueOf(GyroX);
            String y1 = String.valueOf(GyroY);
            String z1 = String.valueOf(GyroZ);
            tv1.setText("AccX = "+x+"\n"+"AccY = "+y+"\n"+"AccZ = "+z+"\n");

            if(mConnectThread.socketAccquired()) {
                    mConnectThread.mConnectedThread.write(float2ByteArray(AccX));
                    mConnectThread.mConnectedThread.write(float2ByteArray(AccY));
                    mConnectThread.mConnectedThread.write(float2ByteArray(AccZ));
                    mConnectThread.mConnectedThread.write(float2ByteArray(GyroX));
                    mConnectThread.mConnectedThread.write(float2ByteArray(GyroY));
                    mConnectThread.mConnectedThread.write(float2ByteArray(GyroZ));
                    mConnectThread.mConnectedThread.write((String.valueOf(clicked)).getBytes());

            }

        }
        else if(mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE){
            GyroX = sensorEvent.values[0];
            GyroY = sensorEvent.values[1];
            GyroZ = sensorEvent.values[2];
            String x = String.valueOf(GyroX);
            String y = String.valueOf(GyroY);
            String z = String.valueOf(GyroZ);
            String x1 = String.valueOf(AccX);
            String y1 = String.valueOf(AccY);
            String z1 = String.valueOf(AccZ);
            tv2.setText("GyroX = "+x+"\n"+"GyroY = "+y+"\n"+"GyroZ = "+z+ "\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "click = " +String.valueOf(clicked));

            if(mConnectThread.socketAccquired()) {

                    mConnectThread.mConnectedThread.write(float2ByteArray(AccX));
                    mConnectThread.mConnectedThread.write(float2ByteArray(AccY));
                    mConnectThread.mConnectedThread.write(float2ByteArray(AccZ));
                    mConnectThread.mConnectedThread.write(float2ByteArray(GyroX));
                    mConnectThread.mConnectedThread.write(float2ByteArray(GyroY));
                    mConnectThread.mConnectedThread.write(float2ByteArray(GyroZ));
                    mConnectThread.mConnectedThread.write((String.valueOf(clicked)).getBytes());

            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

    }


 @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        senSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        if(mConnectThread.socketAccquired()){
            try {
                mConnectThread.mConnectedThread.mmOutStream.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        senSensorManager.registerListener(this,senAccelerometer,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        senSensorManager.registerListener(this,senGyroscope,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }
    public void sendMessage(View view){
        if(clicked){
            clicked = false;
        }
        else{
            clicked = true;
        }
    }
    public static byte [] float2ByteArray (float value)
    {
        return ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putFloat(value).array();
    }
}
```

i am sending individual byte values of sensors to the outputstream and it is working fine as i can see it in the logcat.

client code:

```
public class Bluetooth {

boolean scanFinished = false;
RemoteDevice bluetoothdevice;
String connectionUrl;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        new Bluetooth().go();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Bluetooth.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

private void go() throws Exception {

    scanFinished = false;
    LocalDevice.getLocalDevice().getDiscoveryAgent().startInquiry(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC, new DiscoveryListener() {
        @Override
        public void deviceDiscovered(RemoteDevice btDevice, DeviceClass cod) {
            try {
                 String name = btDevice.getFriendlyName(false);
                if (name.matches("Mi.*")) {

                    System.out.format("%s (%s)\n", name, btDevice.getBluetoothAddress());
                    bluetoothdevice = btDevice;
                    return;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void inquiryCompleted(int discType) {
            scanFinished = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void serviceSearchCompleted(int transID, int respCode) {
        }

        @Override
        public void servicesDiscovered(int transID, ServiceRecord[] servRecord) {
        }
    });
    while (!scanFinished) {

        Thread.sleep(500);
    }


    UUID uuid = new UUID(0x1101); 
    UUID[] searchUuidSet = new UUID[]{uuid};


     LocalDevice.getLocalDevice().getDiscoveryAgent().searchServices(null, searchUuidSet,
            bluetoothdevice, new DiscoveryListener() {
                @Override
                public void deviceDiscovered(RemoteDevice btDevice, DeviceClass cod) {
                }

                @Override
                public void inquiryCompleted(int discType) {
                }

                @Override
                public void serviceSearchCompleted(int transID, int respCode) {
                    scanFinished = true;
                }

                @Override
                public void servicesDiscovered(int transID, ServiceRecord[] servRecord) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < servRecord.length; i++) {
                        connectionUrl = servRecord[i].getConnectionURL(ServiceRecord.NOAUTHENTICATE_NOENCRYPT, false);
                        if (connectionUrl != null) {
                            break; 
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
     if(connectionUrl == null) {
         System.out.println("could not establish connection");return;
     }

  StreamConnection streamConnection = (StreamConnection)Connector.open(connectionUrl);


    while(true) {
        RemoteDevice dev = RemoteDevice.getRemoteDevice(streamConnection);
        System.out.println("Remote device address: "+dev.getBluetoothAddress());
        System.out.println("Remote device name: "+dev.getFriendlyName(true));
        Thread processThread = new Thread(new processConnThread(streamConnection));
        processThread.start();

    }

}
```

so what i am  basically trying to do is get the sensor data from my phone and trying to send it to my pc .i am able to detect my phone "Mi Al" but the connectionUrl seems to be null.

why is the connectionUrl being null?

Comment: Permissions? For Android it's best to add those since they influence behavior. You are asking the system for the connection URL and it gives you null, right? Have you tried putting down a breakpoint and seeing whether it's filled where it should be filled?

Comment: yeah I have included all the permissions required for Bluetooth , the android program is writing on the outputstream , I forgot to mention one thing when I changed the UUID to a different string in both the server and client my connectionUrl is not null and there were no errors but I was not getting any values

Comment: Maybe you can find a simpler example that works, and then compare where it differs from your code? I'd need to build the UI and basically recreate the app on my side to analyze this, and even then it would probably be worthless because I don't have access to the specific device you use. Nulls in Android when calling services in my experience usually mean you're missing a connection to something somewhere, or the device's software build has issues. I've had problems with using older code that called services that had been replaced in the past. Be sure the code works for your version of Android.